# kdb debugging in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: linux, device, drivers

in kernel module programming how we can debug using Kdb? I tried with ubuntu 11.04 but I am not getting correct kdb patch for 2.6.38 kernel version so can any one suggest how to proceed
with kdb debugging under this kernel version?

Answer (score 1):

KDB must be turned on in your kernel. I suspect it is compiled off on Ubuntu default release.

[Here](http://elinux.org/KDB) the details. I expecting you know how to rebuild kernel.